# how to access a field from a another in many to many relation?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models "User" and "Role". Role model is like this:

```
 class Role(models.Model):
     ADMIN = 1
     INFORMATIC = 2
     REFEREE = 3
     SPONSER = 4
     STAFF = 5
     PLAYER = 6
     CUSTOMER =7
     VISITOR = 8

     ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'admin'),
        (2, 'informatic'),
        (3, 'referee'),
        (4, 'sponser'),
        (5, 'staff'),
        (6, 'player'),
        (7, 'customer'),
        (8, 'visitor'),
     )
     id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, primary_key=True , 
        default=VISITOR)
```

and here is my User model:

```
 class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, blank=True , null=True,)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True , blank=True)

    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role)
```

now I have created some Role objects and some Users and assigned some Roles to some Users. now I want to know how can I determine which user has which roles? from request I have the user. I want to know if a User has a role, for example, sponsor, and grants him some permissions.
how can i check this ?

**EDIT**
when i use usrobj.roles.filter() it returns something like this:

```
<QuerySet [<Role: (2, 'informatic')>, <Role: (3, 'referee')>]>
```

and using userobj.roles.filter(id=1) returns like this:

```
<QuerySet [<Role: (2, 'informatic')>]>
```

and obviously this is not what i want

Comment: I don't understand your edit. Why isn't that what you want? In any case, I said to use `.exists()`.

Comment: I got it. i did something silly. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the role directly and check `.exists()`:

```
request.user.roles.filter(id=1).exists()
```

(Note, I *really* don't recommend using the ID as the choice in the Role model. Use a separate `role` field.)

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want to know if someone is an admin:

In a view:

```
admin_role = Role.objects.get(id=1)
admin_users = User.objects.filter(roles__in=admin_role)

# To check if a user is admin
if admin_role in user.roles.all():
    pass
```

Good luck!